# Check if sidebar is active on page with id

Tags: pages, sidebar

How can i check if a certain sidebar is active on a certain page from functions.php using page id or some other page meta data?

Comment: it depends what do you mean by "active"... do mean if it is in the page layout or has widgets in it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
if (is_active_sidebar($sidebar-name) && is_page($page-id)) {do your thing}
```

?